# Reading rosrun command line arguments inside your node?

Tags: rosparam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosrun my_package my_node _param_int:=1 _param_string:="test"

How do I read this inside of the node? I couldn't find something in the tutorials.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249061/reading-rosrun-command-line-arguments-inside-your-node?/) by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1133 on 2016-11-29

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The call to `ros::init()` will parse `argc` and `argv` looking for the `:=` operator and seting private parameters and remappings. It then modifies `argc` and `argv`to leave any unrecognized command-line parameters for your code to parse. This behavior is documented in [roscpp Initialization and Shutdown](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown)

Per the documentation on [remapping arguments](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments), any remapping arguments that start with `_` are interpreted as setting a private parameter, and other arguments that do not start with `_` are interpreted as topic remappings.

As described in [roscpp Parameters](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Parameter%20Server), you can retrieve private parameters by creating a private NodeHandle and calling `getParam()` on it:

```
ros::NodeHandle nh("~");
std::string param;
nh.getParam("private_name", param);
```

It's also possible to retrieve remappings from a NodeHandle object, but unless you're explicitly trying to use this for more complex topic or service remappings within your node, it's not recommended.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2016-11-30**:
Ah, what `ros::init()` does was the missing piece for me - that's sorted now. Thanks.